# Read multiple JSON files as one array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, frontend

I currently have two JSON files that my array needs to read. Is there a way for me to read them as one array?

I've already tried putting both in a constant variable but it did not work. It was something like this which obviously is not the solution:

```
const var = [{json_file_1}, {json_file_2}];
```

I did also try lodash but I still didn't find the solution but I also have a console.log line for the code above.

```
console.log(_.flattenDeep(ThisFunction(var)));
```

ThisFunction() reads the contents of my json.

Here is my current array. It is only reading one json file:

```
const option = json_file_1
   .map(group => (
    <div key={group.title}>
      <div>
        {group.title}
      </div>
      {group.child_one.map(object => (
        <div key={object.title}>
          {object.title}
        </div>
      ))
    </div>
));
```

Both of JSON files go something like this:

```
[
 {
   "title": "this title",
   "child_one": [
      {
        "content_1",
        "content_2"
      }
   ],
   "child_two": [
    {
      "title" "this title",
      "something": "something else"
    },
    {
      "title" "this title",
      "something": "something else"
    }
   ]
 }
]
```

The output should read the two files as one array. Once this is done, will I be able to integrate more JSON files to be read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you could't do it with

> const var = [{json_file_1}, {json_file_2}];

is that you create two object in your array. However you can simply use spread operator.

So you can use it like this and pass this var to your component.

```
const var = [...json_file_1, ...json_file_2];
```

If couldn't explain it clearly please say so I can describe with more detail.

Comment: I tried it and it gives an error that says ".default is not iterable"

Comment: hmm, can you console log your json file after you imported it?

Comment: I did and it's showing the contents of my json. I just posted an answer as well.

Comment: I'm still getting an error most probably its because I'm using react hooks and my syntax is probably wrong.

Comment: OK, I saw your answer an update my answer according to your needs. You don't have to use flatten function because spread operator will do it for you if your data isn't too nested.

Comment: @octubus Thanks dude! Helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution but I don't believe this is the best since I am getting loads of console errors because some of my dummy data are the same

```
const var = [{json_file_1}, {jsone_file_2}];
```

and I passed it to my `AutoComplete` input

```
<AutoComplete onSearch={_.flattenDeep(ThisFunction(var))}></AutoComplete>
```

*As mentioned above, ThisFunction() reads the arrays and nested arrays inside my JSON file*